# How to set Async send with JmsPooledConnectionFactory in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

In *ActiveMQ in Action* the author states as one of the performance tuning possibilities for ActiveMQ is to set the `AsyncSend` flag for `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. In my case I want to use the `JmsPoolConnectionFactory` to create a pool of connection and in the same time set the `AsyncSend` flag. However, I cannot seem to find a way to to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `jms.useAsyncSend=true` on the connection's URL as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/async-sends), e.g.:

```
tcp://locahost:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which pooling implementation you are using the way it is created might differ a bit but in general they all just accept an external JMS ConnectionFactory instance and then create JMS resources from there.  So this implies that if you want to set configuration that is specific to your own JMS provider then you should be doing that through the ConnectionFactory that you pass to the pool's ConnectionFactory proxy.